# After Deleting Items by AJAX, page scrolling up

Tags: php, ajax

Description : Hello I am developing Online food ordering site. I have almost completed the project but i am stuck at shopping cart..

Problem: I am facing problem when i delete the item from the cart which i have selected the page is scrolling up when i delete item from the cart.. I am using AJAX to add and delete items from the cart.

What will be the possible solution so that page do not scroll up when i delete the item from cart.??

You can check out here is the link : http://gogaily.com/restaurant_details.php?hotel_id=14   after page redirects click on MENU tab to view Menu items ... When u click on Menu items Cart will be displayed ,once u delete the item from cart Page scroll up.. How to avoid the page getting scrolled up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s because you are using a link element with `href="#"` – the empty hash gets treated as “scroll to top” by browsers.

You simple have to suppress the “normal” link functionality after executing your JS code – keywords are `event.preventDefault` or `return false` (the latter for “traditional” event handling.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have used anchor tag in delete button. ie.

```
<a href="#" ...>Delete</a>
```

something like this. Do it with

```
<a href="">Delete</a>
```

or use button i.e.

```
<button ...>Delete</button>
```

Hope you problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Replace href="#" with href="javascript:void();"

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0